# isset($_POST['submit']) issue

Tags: php, javascript

I'm having hard times  finding out why the code doesn't work...
so there's a form with a submit button whitch is supposed to be disabled after the request is sent.

php:

```
<form action="buy.php" method="post" onsubmit="zapret()">
....
<input id="submitOtbor" type="submit" name="submit" value="Отправить" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
function zapret()
{
   var btn = document.getElementById(\'submitOtbor\').disabled = true;
   $(\'#result_5\').show();
   return false;

}
```

well, after the submit button is pressed isset($_POST['submit']) in buy.php can't catch variables from the form...

could someone help me with that?

Comment: why are you escaping the single quotes in javascript?

Comment: because originally the code included in php like: echo ' some code here.. ';

Answer (score 3):

You disabled the submit button. Disabled controls are, by definition, not "successful" and will not be sent in the data to the server.

If you want the data to show up, don't disable the button.

(You could also generate a hidden input with the same name, but really, don't disable submit buttons. It makes it hard to resubmit a form when a request fails).

Comment: thanks for help! now the code is working fine. I'm really happy )))

Answer (score 1):

So why depend on a control that's disabled (which in turn would not be carried over--a default behavior for all browsers to ignore disabled controls)?

You can always check `!empty($_POST)`. Alternatively, you can add a hidden field that symbolizes the form's intent. e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="create|read|delete" />
```

That *would* be passed off in a submit.

Comment: thanks for help! now the code is working fine. I'm really happy )))